# Adding a second modem to my network

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp, dsl-modem

We are a dozen of people on a small network with one DSL modem, and one netgear switch that connects to a patch panel to distribute the wires to all rooms of the office. The DHCP is disabled on the modem, I have a Windows Server 2012 taking care of this.

We got a "deal" for a second modem (second internet connection), although the need  is debatable, I still have to configure it and I don't know exactly what to do. The new modem is a Bell Hub 2000.

What I was thinking to do:

- Change the IP address of the modem (currently 192.168.2.1) to 192.168.3.x because our network is using subnet 3.  But when I disable DHCP on the modem I no longer have access to change its IP. I am hoping the DHCP could attribute a new IP address automatically to this modem?
- Plug the modem on my switch
- I am not sure what to do on my windows domain, so the internet load is split on both modems?

Please point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Look at dual-WAN routers. E.g. DrayTek, of which I've used in the past. You don't need to change much on your existing LAN. A typical dual-WAN setup could work liek this: https://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2018/01_w02/1218397/Single-WAN-vs.-Dual-WAN.png - note the red X showing that one Internet connection can fail and the other will continue to work. It can do fail-over or load-balancing. The dual-WAN router will become your LAN "gateway" as it manages the modem/ISP addresses on the WAN side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a load-balancer device, where the load-balancer will become your gateway.
It is the load-balancer that will route traffics, based on a selected algorithm,
to the ISPs.

I know of one software open source load-balancer : [Zen Loadbalancer](https://www.zenloadbalancer.com/community/downloads/),
which can also be installed in a virtual machine
(but have never used it).